# Неравномерно распределяются пункты в меню

Tags: html, css, меню

В `menu__list` с помощью `d-flex justify-content-between` пункты не размещаются равномерно, что не так?

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__list d-flex justify-content-between ">
    <a href="#about" class="menu__link">
      <li class="menu__item">
        Обо мне
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#skills" class="menu__link">
      <li class="menu__item">
        Навыки
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#work" class="menu__link">
      <li class="menu__item">
        Работы
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: *не размещаются равномерно* значит, что они уже чем надо?

Comment: А где CSS  ?????

Answer (score 1):

```css
nav.menu {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu__list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__list d-flex justify-content-between ">
    <a href="#about" class="menu__link">
      <li class="menu__item">
        Обо мне
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#skills" class="menu__link">
      <li class="menu__item">
        Навыки
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#work" class="menu__link">
      <li class="menu__item">
        Работы
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Всё хорошо работает. Может у Вас ширина контейнера маленькая? Либо опечатка.

Comment: Поздравляю Вас с достижением `2000`!

Comment: Ширина,вообще была не задана,спасибо всем ребята,все исправила, все получилось, для начинающего это большое достижение маленькими шагами

Comment: @НатальяKравченко, желаю успехов в начинаниях!

Comment: Спасибо, meine!!!